# C++ error No matching member function for call to addtoucheventlistener

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, cocostudio

I'm new with cocos2d-x. I'm getting error in this line :

```
Button* btnRegister=static_cast<Button*>(Helper::seekWidgetByName(m_pLayout, "btnRegister"));
btnRegister->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_0(LoginScene::GameLoginTest, this));//get error no matching member function for call to addtoucheventlistener
```

I don't know why cause i have already create one constructor below
Please help, what should i do to fix that

File LoginScene.h

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "cocos-ext.h"
#include "CocosGUI.h"

USING_NS_CC;
USING_NS_CC_EXT;

using namespace ui;

class LoginScene : public Scene
{
public:
    LoginScene(bool pPortrait=false);
    ~LoginScene();
    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
    //static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    //virtual bool init();

    virtual void onEnter();
    virtual void onExit();

    // a selector callback
    virtual void GameLogin();
    void GameLoginTest(Ref* pSender,TouchEventType type);
    //virtual void runThisTest()=0;
protected:

    Layer* m_pUILayer;
    Layout* m_pLayout;
    int authenticate();
    //int authenticate(const char* username, const char* password);
    // implement the "static create()" method manually
    //CREATE_FUNC(LoginScene);
};
```

File LoginScene.cpp

```
#include "LoginScene.h"
#include "cocostudio/CCSSceneReader.h"
#include "cocostudio/CCSGUIReader.h"
#include "cocostudio/CCActionManagerEx.h"
#include "LoadingScene.h"
#include "MainScene.h"
#include "curl/curl.h"

LoginScene::LoginScene(bool pPortrait):m_pUILayer(NULL),m_pLayout(NULL)
{
    Scene::init();
}

LoginScene::~LoginScene()
{

}

void LoginScene::onEnter()
{
    Scene::onEnter();

    m_pUILayer=Layer::create();
    m_pUILayer->scheduleUpdate();
    this->addChild(m_pUILayer);

    m_pLayout=dynamic_cast<Layout*>(cocostudio::GUIReader::getInstance()->widgetFromJsonFile("LoginScene.json"));
    m_pUILayer->addChild(m_pLayout);

    Button* btnLogin = static_cast<Button*>(Helper::seekWidgetByName(m_pLayout, "btnLogin"));
    btnLogin->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_0(LoginScene::GameLogin, this));//it's okay

    Button* btnRegister=static_cast<Button*>(Helper::seekWidgetByName(m_pLayout, "btnRegister"));
    btnRegister->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_0(LoginScene::GameLoginTest, this));
    //get error no matching member function for call to addtoucheventlistener

}
void LoginScene::GameLogin()
{
    auto scene=LoadingScene::createScene();
    Director::getInstance()->pushScene(scene);
}

void LoginScene::GameLoginTest(Ref* pSender,TouchEventType type)
{
    if (type==TOUCH_EVENT_ENDED)
    {
        if (authenticate()==1)
        {
            auto scene=MainScene::createScene();
            Director::getInstance()->pushScene(TransitionFade::create(2.3f, scene));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for LoginScene::GameLoginTest, maybe you can use CC_CALLBACK_2,like this:
btnRegister->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(LoginScene::GameLoginTest, this));

Comment: Tks 4 answer, i have checked CC_CALLBACK with another number but same error :(
Do u have any idea with my constructor?
void LoginScene::GameLoginTest(Ref* pSender,TouchEventType type)

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of the functor you are sending is

(LoginScene* , Ref*  , TouchEventType)

Since LoginTest is not a static method, it has an implicit parameter called "this".

You have two options :

- make the function static
- change the prototype to just TouchEventType (I believe that Ref* is meant to be "this").

Comment: sorry man :D i dont have enough 15 reputations to vote :p
anyway tks so much

Comment: NP :) . Enjoy C++ ;).